# Browser Refresh Required on Angular Application After Each Deployment

Tags: angular

We have a problem that occurs after each deployment of our Angular application to our production and QA web servers. After deploying, the application doesn't work until you hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Refresh.  We have tried different switches when using ng-build, including the "--output-hashing all" option.

We are currently running:
Angular CLI: 1.7.4
Node: 6.10.3
Angular: 5.2.3

Currently we are using "ng build --prod --env=qa".  The first error we see in the console is always "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <".

Before I paste the rest of the error below, want to point out that a CTRL-Refresh always solves this problem with no other action, but it is unacceptable to ask our users to remember to hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-Refresh every morning, and we are on a daily deployment schedule.  Any help is much appreciated!  Here is the rest of the error from the console:

```
main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
    at HTMLScriptElement.b (inline.3d41eb1ccb98ee445ffc.bundle.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.E (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at y (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.b (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.b (inline.3d41eb1ccb98ee445ffc.bundle.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.E (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at y (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at HTMLScriptElement.b (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at P (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1)
    at t.invokeTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at e.runTask (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at v (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at e.invokeTask [as invoke] (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
    at y (polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1)
K @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.handleError @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.object.r @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.__tryOrUnsub @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.emit @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.invoke @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.run @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
t.runOutsideAngular @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
onHandleError @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.handleError @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.runGuarded @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
t @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
n.microtaskDrainDone @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
v @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
y @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
b @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
error (async)
O @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
onScheduleTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
t.scheduleTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.scheduleEventTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
O.o.set @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
a.e @ inline.3d41eb1ccb98ee445ffc.bundle.js:1
r @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.loadFactory @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.load @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.loadModuleFactory @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.load @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._tryNext @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t._trySubscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
PIsA.e.a @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._innerSub @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._tryNext @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t._trySubscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
PIsA.e.a @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._innerSub @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._tryNext @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e.next @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
e._subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t._trySubscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.call @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.subscribe @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
t.forEach @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
t.runNavigate @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.invoke @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
onInvoke @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.invoke @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.run @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
(anonymous) @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
onInvokeTask @ main.2ef68a54d7f9448f51b4.bundle.js:1
t.invokeTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.runTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
v @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
e.invokeTask @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
y @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
b @ polyfills.81eb2d8b886832be573a.bundle.js:1
5.17c21d79043279ea6b1f.chunk.js:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Comment: Are all the bundle files replaced when new build is deployed? It might be related to the fact that while the application is running files get replace on server or wherever you are hosting  the app. However, the current app still has references to old javascript files in index.html and when user navigates to another lazy module browser tries to load  a file which doesn't exist on the server anymore.

Comment: Yes, I delete all of the files in the destination folder except for the web.config file whenever I deploy.

Comment: Are you using the `index.html` file from the Angular CLI output or serving up your own html file?

Comment: @cac_software_factory, well, if you keep the bundle files it will ensure that users who have their tabs with the app opened will be able to use it (old version of the app). However index.html should be replaced to provide any new user of the app with fresh bundle references from index.html

Comment: We are using the index.html file from the Angular CLI output. When we deploy, we deploy our Angular application at the same time as our .Net application because our controllers are in the .Net application. We don't want users to be able to use the old version of the Angular app because it may or may not be compatible with the newly deployed .Net application.

Comment: Are you using service workers?

Comment: @KimKern We are not using service workers.  I have also confirmed that we are not using AppCache.

Comment: Also we have attempted to prevent caching in our index.html file using these meta tags:  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate">
  <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
  <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0">

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: We have "sort of" solved this problem.  We have a "version-check" service that compares the current response.hash to the current hash.  If it has changed, we reload the application after prompting the user to do so.  This works for users who are currently in the system when a deployment occurs.  While this improves our end user experience, I find that after deploying, I still have to hit CTRL-Refresh to reload the application.  After deploying the client, I typically open a browser and navigate to the site, and always have to hit CTRL-Refresh to get things to work.